# Return variable from @Patch @Delete located in url - #${id}. Lesson 12 in NestJS course

Tags: typescript, nestjs

[image]

I'm at the very beggining of NestJS course. Insomnia and localhost seem to work well. On @Get request there is no problem to return a simple message, but for example in @Patch or @Delete decorator, when the tutorial says to return `lorem ipsum #${id}` where ${id} should be localhost:3000/coffes/**726** and just return "*lorem ipsum 726*" it returns it not finding the variable.

`return "lorem ipsum #${id}"` returns *return "lorem ipsum #${id}* instead of *return "lorem ipsum 726*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return this message, because the id isn't parsed in your expression :

```
return `this action updates ${id}`
```

check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more informations

Comment: Thank you. Seems pretty silly now, but it was all about the tick ` character instead of apostrophe '. I'll double check the documentation next time.

Comment: You're welcome, it happens to everyone, good luck with Nests it's a great framework